# FFT result; amplitude-phase relation

Tags: python, numpy

I want to amplify audio input at specific frequencies, and I use `numpy.fft`.

So my question is: When changing the amplitudes of the signal, what happens with phase?

For example, if I multiply amplitudes in some frequency range, by some factor, let's say 2, do I need to change the phases, and if so, what should I do with them?

I've done the amplification without changing phases, and the result was not what I wanted. It's pretty much the same signal, with some unwanted noise.

Answer (score 7):

You shouldn't need the change the phase for something like this.  More likely the problem is that you need to be a bit more gentle about applying the boost.  It sounds like you are taking some frequency window and multiplying by a constant while leaving everything else unchanged.  This will cause ringing in the time domain with a very long tail.  You need to smooth the transition from the gain=1 region to the gain=2 region, for instance by using a gaussian waveform with code that looks something like this:

```
x, t = get_waveform()
f0, df = get_parameters()     # Center frequency and bandwidth of gain region
f = np.fft.rfft(x)
freqs = np.fft.fftfreq(len(x), t[1]-t[0])
freqs = freqs[0:len(f)]       # rfft has only non-negative frequency components
gain_window = 1 + np.exp(-(freqs-f0)**2/(df)**2)
f = f * gain_window
x = np.fft.irfft(f)
return x
```

If that works, you can experiment with more aggressive functions that have sharper turn-on and a flatter top.

The FFT may not actually be what you want.  FFTs are not normally used for real-time / streaming applications.  This is because in the naive approach you have to collect the whole sample buffer before you start processing.  For simple filtering applications it is often easier to do filtering directly in the time domain.  This is what FIR and IIR filters do.

In order to filter with the fourier transform in real time what you have to do is break your data stream into overlapping blocks of a fixed length, FFT, filter, reverse FFT, and stich them back together without introducing glitches.  This is possible, but it is tricky to get right.  For a full-blown multi-channel EQ it might still be the best option, but you should at least consider time domain filtering.

If this is not a real-time application, then FFT is the way to go.  For medium sized data sets (up to a few hundred megabytes) you can just FFT the whole data set.  For much larger data sets you still have to break the data up into blocks, but they can be much larger blocks and you don't have to worry about the latency introduced.

Also, remember the FFT treats the signal as periodic, so if your signal doesn't go to zero at the beginning and end you will need to do some sort of windowing.